# How can i combine bootstrap with ransack?

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ransack

I am trying to build a form builder in Rails with bootstrap and ransack, but is not workink

My file _form is working the bootstrap form

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@voluntario, layout: :horizontal) do |f| %>
  <% if @voluntario.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@voluntario.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this voluntario from being saved:</h2>
```

But in my file index is not working, actually i use the gem ransack in the index

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<% contacto = {
      'Promotores voluntarios' => 'Promotores voluntarios', 'Promotores capacitantes' => 'Promotores capacitantes'} %>
    <%= f.label :contacto_cont, "Tipo de Contacto" %>
   <%= f.select :contacto_cont,contacto, include_blank: true %>
  </div>
```

How can i combine the bootstrap form_for with ransack form_for in my index?

Comment: How is your code failing? I wonder if a `method_missing` is defined which matches any `<type>_form_form`. If this were the only problem (one of your form_for methods not being called) then you could solve it by rewriting the forms by hand. While form builders are convenient, making them by hand [tutorial](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/form-basics) gives you more fine-grained control.